# How to get notified about file content changes in NetBeans with DataObject API

Tags: java, netbeans-platform, netbeans-7.3

I'm trying to implement a NavigatorPanel for my NetBeans module.
Now I would like to always get notified whenever the associated DataObject was modified so that I can invoke the parser and update the navigator.

I tried adding a PropertyChangeListener to the DataObject, but that only notifies me about the first change made to the document and that's it. However, I've noticed that the first time PropertyChangeListener.propertyChange() method is invoked, the propertyName is set to "COOKIE" and the second time to "MODIFIED".

Any ideas on how to **always** get notified when the content of the document in the editor (not the underlying FileObject!) has changed?

**EDIT:**
I already looked at http://wiki.netbeans.org/DevFaqListenForSaveEvents. They state that the PropertyChangeListener is used for getting informed about documents being saved (e.g. by Ctrl+S) and if one wants to be notified about modifications to the content, FileChangeListener should be used instead. But that didn't work for me. In either case I don't get notified when I'm modifying the document in the editor, except for when using PropertyChangeListener, then I do get notified, but only the first time I edit something (exactly the opposite as what they write in the FAQ).

**EDIT2:**
I haven't figured out how to get properly notified yet. But in my case I should have actually approached my goal from a different perspective, i.e. since I want to update the NavigatorPanel based on parsing results, I should probably be registering a ParserResultTask. By that I can define when I should get notified, and when I do get notified I also get the already parsed results I would need for updating the panel.

Well, this is not a direct answer to the actual question but a more suitable solution for this particular problem.

Comment: Did you say you already looked at this ? http://wiki.netbeans.org/DevFaqListenForSaveEvents

Answer (score 1):

Here is something that works for me. Mind you that an event is fired only when you save your changes. Note that the code below might not compile well as I have deleted my code to make it concise. But it is as simple as implementing FileChangeListener on your DataObject. Geertjan did a blog post on this a while ago. Let me know how it goes.

https://blogs.oracle.com/geertjan/entry/org_openide_filesystems_filechangelistener

```
public class YourDataObject extends MultiDataObject implements FileChangeListener {


    public YourDataObject(FileObject pf, MultiFileLoader loader) throws DataObjectExistsException, IOException {
        super(pf, loader);
        pf.addFileChangeListener(this);
        registerEditor("text/x-puml", true);
    }

    @Override
    protected int associateLookup() {
        return 1;
    }


    @Override
    public void fileFolderCreated(FileEvent fe) {}

    @Override
    public void fileDataCreated(FileEvent fe) {}

    @Override
    public void fileChanged(FileEvent fe) {
        System.out.println("Here =========== :" + fe);
    }

    @Override
    public void fileDeleted(FileEvent fe) {}

    @Override
    public void fileRenamed(FileRenameEvent fre) {}

    @Override
    public void fileAttributeChanged(FileAttributeEvent fae) {}
}
```

**EDIT**

Nevermind, I forgot you didn't want to deal with FileObject. Here is a netbeans forum post.

http://forums.netbeans.org/ptopic7909.html

Comment: Thank you, was close but not quite what I was looking for. However, along the way I realized something. See my Edit2 in the first post.